# Appium: iOS, real device, driver.hidekeyboard() doesn't operate

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I'm using Appium on Mac OS with iPhone 5S with operation system 9.2.
When i'm trying to hide the Keyboard with the method:

```
driver.hidekeyboard();
```

Nothing happens and the application crash.
Need help please

Thanks 
Ohad

Comment: If the app (ios) is crashing, you might want that to be fixed on the app code. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Yes, i think its your app issue. Otherwise give this a try driver.navigate.back();

Answer (score 0):

If in case your application is crashing on when you are trying to hide the keyboard, then that could be a possible bug you are looking at and to understand the cause of that and get it fixed would be the topmost recommendation. Your statement

```
driver.hidekeyboard();
```

is good enough for what you desire out of the execution assuming the driver used is AppiumDriver or its subclass.

Also if you are sure that the keyboard is displayed and you can even manually hide the keyboard, a forced way to do that is as @Gaurav has suggested in the comments using the following code :

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

In case of uncertainty of the visibility of keyboard, you can give this a try :

```
driver.getKeyboard();
driver.hideKeyboard();
```